# Setting maximum fps on a Sprite/Image?

Tags: uiimageview, ios7, uikit-dynamics

Specifically on a UIImageView. I'm using IOS7 dynamics and a "rope-like" dynamic, when I click and drag the image attached to the rope(Dragon*) it goes like 130 FPS(Just way to fast)! So I was wondering if there was some method that can make your Image/Sprite go a "speed limit" that you set.

Like If Dragon goes past this FPS(or maybe another measurement) have Dragon go back to this speed.

I hope this is clear! Thanks :D